# Throttling on vert.x application

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry, vert.x

I have a vert.x application which is hosted on Cloud Foundry. I have to implement a throttling condition that limits the requests on basis of free memory, in a way InterceptorHandler does in Spring. So is there a way to intercept HTTP Requests to server before the request actually reaching the memory of the server?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "reaching the memory of the server"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your intent is to throttle the request as quick as possible, and that's what you mean by "not reaching the memory".

For that purpose, you can use a simple global handler, since in Vert.x every handler is an interceptor of sorts.

```
    router.route().handler(ctx -> {
        // Probably you want to check some request properties
       if (isThrottled(ctx)) {
           ctx.response().setStatusCode(504).end();
       }
       else {
           // All is good, continue
           ctx.next();
       }
    });
```

I also must note, though, that Vert.x has a constant memory footprint, unlike Spring, since Vert.x uses limited number of threads. This number is not influenced by the amount of incoming requests. So I wouldn't advice throttling based on memory.

Comment: you probably want to add `.end()` after setting the status code

Comment: Thanks! That's what happens when you don't test your code :)